# Opening a file in Python return a stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple qustion related opening file in Python.

Doing something like this:

```
x = open('test.txt', 'rt')
print(x)
```

I obtain this output:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='rt' encoding='cp1252'>
```

that is the Python object representing the opened file. Is it considerable a stream or not? What exactly represents a stream in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [official documents of python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), it is a stream.

> The easiest way to create a text stream is with open(), optionally specifying an encoding:
>
> `f = open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Text I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) section of the docs,

> The easiest way to create a text stream is with `open()`, optionally specifying an encoding

Which seems to indicate an affirmative to the question of whether it is *considerable a stream*. Whether the usage of the term ‘stream’ here is consistent with that in other languages is indeterminate.

It also bears noting the object returned, and consequently its characteristics, is subject to the mode used,

> The type of file object returned by the open() function depends on the mode. When open() is used to open a file in a text mode ('w', 'r', 'wt', 'rt', etc.), it returns a subclass of io.TextIOBase (specifically io.TextIOWrapper). When used to open a file in a binary mode with buffering, the returned class is a subclass of io.BufferedIOBase. The exact class varies: in read binary mode, it returns an io.BufferedReader; in write binary and append binary modes, it returns an io.BufferedWriter, and in read/write mode, it returns an io.BufferedRandom. When buffering is disabled, the raw stream, a subclass of io.RawIOBase, io.FileIO, is returned.

[`io.BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase), [`io.RawIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), and [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) explicitly state in their documentation that they are base classes for streams.